# value from one array as index for another array in smarty

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

i am trying to get values belonging to an order in select box. 
in

> $wri_cat_lev[$orders[i].order_num]

if i put

> $wri_cat_lev[5666767]

which is an order number it works fine

> {$orders[i].order_num}

gives

> 5666767

but when i use the code below it doesn't work gives me just A as result

> {foreach
>   from=$wri_cat_lev[$orders[i].order_num]
>   item="first"}
>
> > {$first.name}
>
> {/foreach}

can anyone tell me how to use value from one array as index for another array in smarty

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
$wri_cat_lev[$orders[i].order_num]
```

be

```
$wri_cat_lev[$orders[$i].order_num]
```

?